# Can Sitecore Clones Become More Automatic

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, items

I have read what I can on cloning and it seems like a partial solution for our client.  I read http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2010/10/Cloning-What-Ifs.aspx but the commenters didn't finish out the answer.

Sitecore clones give notification on changes which is nice and supports the idea of workflow for all items, but the clone parent does not give information on what is cloned from it. So when a change is made on our (mainly) master site, finding each cloned item in the 5 sister sites is going to become much too tedious too fast.

I believe that proxy items would have once been the true solution, but considering that they are deprecated, I don't think it's a solution we are looking to implement.

**Besides modifying our workflow and messing around with the clones, is there a built-in or easier way to maintain clones?**

**Desired Behavior**:
When parent of clones becomes approved into a final workflow state => Accept the changes on the clones as well.
Or
**Less Desired**:
Give a list of all child clones of an item in the Content Editor with links to edit.

Comment: check this link http://gositecore.blogspot.com/2012/10/sitecore-cloned-items-and-workflow.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For your desired behavior**: you'd have to implement either an event handler or pipeline processor that when an item is approved, you use the Links Database to find all clones of it and programmatically approve those. I believe this is certainly do-able from a code perspective.

**For your less desired behavior**: you can use the **Navigate** tab > **Links** drop-down to find clones. Just look at the *Referrers* that have the **_source** field displayed, meaning they refer to that item via the "_source" field which means they're a clone of it.

**UPDATE**

To modify the workflow of an item via C#, refer to [Changing the Workflow State on an Item](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Snippets/Workflow/Change%20the%20Workflow%20State%20on%20an%20Item%20via%20API.aspx).

Comment: Ah. So pretty much what I thought. Mark, do you happen to have any links with the clone API? I went looking for a bit but I couldn't find out how to accept changes on the clones. Is it just updating the fields on the clone from the master before approving?

Comment: It's not a "clone API" as a clone is just an item with the "__source" field filled out. You want to look into using the Sitecore API to programmatically apply workflow. I've edited my answer above with a link.

Comment: As Mark pointed out, clones are just items. This is an article written by John West in which he explains clones in some detail that might help explain some more about how clones work:  http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/10/Sitecore-CMS-6-4-Cloning.aspx

Comment: @MarkUrsino Do you know which pipeline you'd need to bind to to do this?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a good pipeline for it but if you tap into the `item:saved` event, check to see if the item's workflow state is updated to a Final state, and if so do your thing...